# Ways to make this simple not threadsafe counter class threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Heres a simple not thread safe Counter class that I would like to make thread safe.

```
public class Counter{
private static int val = 0;

public Counter() {
}

public static void set(int newVal) {
    val = newVal;
}

public static void decrement() {
    int tmp = val;

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100L);
    } catch (Exception var2) {
        ;
    }

    --tmp;
    val = tmp;
}

public static boolean depleted() {
    return val == 0;
}

}
```

I know of the `synchronised` way, and have implemented that below:

```
public static synchronised void decrement() {
    val--
}
```

Now im trying to figure out any other simple ways to make the class thread safe?

Particularly Im looking at the java library `java.util.concurrent` and `atomic data structures`. How would i go about implementing these? Even an explanation on them, and like pseudocode would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: Why the downvotes? Im trying to learn  :(

Comment: Use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: Just making decrement synchronized does not make it thread-safe. Every method accessing val needs to be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

The simple ways are:

- Make all methods of `Counter` `synchronized`.
- Make the `Counter` class a wrapper for a `AtomicInteger` instance.
- Just use `AtomicInteger` instead.

---

It is worth noting that this is a bad idea:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(100L);
} catch (Exception var2) {
    ;
}
```

A properly implement counter should not arbitrarily delay a call.  It is not part of the "spec" (i.e. expected behavior) of a counter.

And if the purpose of the `sleep(100L)` call is to (somehow) help you prove that your counter code is thread-safe, it won't:

- It is *not possible* to prove that code is thread-safe by running it and looking at what it does.  This approach only gives you invalid "proofs", and a false sense of what your code is doing.
- It could actually cause *serendipitous* synchronization due to some unspecified synchronizing effect of the `Thread.sleep(...)` call.  Adding a `sleep` (or a print or log statement) is liable to *change* the behavior multi-threaded code.  (Just like, running it using a debugger will do.)

Also, it is a *bad idea* to catch `Exception`.  Catch the specific exceptions that you are expecting.  Catching "everything" can cause you to catch things that are actually evidence of bugs in your code.  (In general, if not here.)  Doing this is a bad coding habit, and it is likely to hurt you sometime in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of an integer to keep track of coints. 
It provides atomic methods like, [`decrementAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#decrementAndGet--) and [`getAndSet(int newValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndSet-int-).